# Efficiently extract edges with biggest weight for each node igraph

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, igraph

I have a weighted undirected simple graph.
The number of nodes is around the tens of thousands and so does the number of edges (it's a sparse graph / matrix).

For each node, I want to find the maximum edge weight ("max score") and store it in a data frame along with the nodes who share that edge. The data frame will have three columns: `node_name` - str, `max_score` - float [0-1], `max_score_nodes` - List[str]

My current solution is provided below, but it's not elegant, there are multiple list comprehensions (one of them is nested) inside a for loop, checking for nodes without edges etc. and I feel there's a smarter way of doing this.

```
import string
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nodes = list(string.ascii_letters[0:6].upper())
edges = [("A", "F"), ("A", "C"), ("F", "D"), ("D", "C"), ("D", "E")]
weights = [0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9]

w_graph = ig.Graph(directed=False)
w_graph.add_vertices(nodes)
w_graph.add_edges(edges, {"weight": weights})

records = {}
for node in nodes:
    local_edges = np.array(w_graph.vs.find(node).all_edges())
    if local_edges.size == 0:
        records.update({node: {"max_score": 0, "max_score_nodes": np.nan}})
        continue
    local_weights = [local_edge["weight"] for local_edge in local_edges]

    max_score = np.max(local_weights)
    max_score_ind = np.where(local_weights == max_score)[0]
    max_score_edges = local_edges[max_score_ind]

    vertex_tuples = [edge.vertex_tuple for edge in max_score_edges]
    max_score_nodes = [
        [vertex["name"] for vertex in vertex_tuple if vertex["name"] != node][0] for
        vertex_tuple in vertex_tuples]

    records.update({node: {"max_score": max_score, "max_score_nodes": max_score_nodes}})

output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records, orient="index")
output_with_node_name = output.rename_axis("node_name").reset_index()
print(output_with_node_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered SciPy's [csr matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) which efficiently handles sparse matrix in a compressed row format.

There's an [igraph method](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html#get_adjacency_sparse) which returns the graph's adjacency matrix as a CSR matrix.

From here we can utilize vectorized operations on rows, so the whole nested for loop is now reduced into 4 lines:

```
scores_matrix = w_graph.get_adjacency_sparse(attribute="weight")

node_names = w_graph.vs["name"]
max_scores = scores_matrix.max(axis=0).toarray()[0]
max_score_nodes = w_graph.vs[scores_matrix.argmax(axis=0).tolist()[0]]["name"]
max_score_nodes = np.where(max_scores == 0, np.nan, max_score_nodes)

output = pd.DataFrame({"node_name": node_names,
                       "max_score": max_scores,
                       "max_score_nodes": max_score_nodes})
print(output)
```

The problem is that `argmax` will return only a single index, if you want to have all node_names with `max_score` you can loop like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import find

max_score_nodes = []
for node_index in w_graph.vs.indices:
    max_score = max_scores[node_index]
    if max_score == 0:
        max_score_nodes.append(np.nan)
        continue

    max_score_node_ind = find(scores_matrix.getrow(node_index) == max_score)[1]
    max_score_node_names = w_graph.vs[max_score_node_ind.tolist()]["name"]
    max_score_nodes.append(max_score_node_names)

output["max_score_nodes"] = max_score_nodes
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build your graph like this:

```
import igraph as ig
from igraph import Graph
```

```
g = Graph.Formula('A, B, C, D, E, F, A-F, A-C, F-D-C, D-E')
g.es['weight'] = [0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9]
```

Get the index of the highest weight edge for each vertex:

```
strongest_edges = [max(edges, key=g.es['weight'].__getitem__) for edges in g.get_inclist()]
```

Get the endpoints of each of these edges:

```
[g.es[eid].tuple for eid in strongest_edges]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it taught me new igraph methods so + 1 but currently it doesn't work on my example since your graph is missing node B which has no edges. Also in the final output instead of a list tuples with two node ids, I would like to have a list of dicts with the max_weight and a single node name (as seen in output_with_node_name) so the last list comprehension needs modification